# 500 JHtml image not found

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I am using `Joomla 3.1` please help fix error 500 `JHtml` image not found.

```
<?php                                   
$link=JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_joomleague&task=project.edit&cid[]='.$this->project->id);
$text=JText::_('COM_JOikOMLEAGUE_P_MENU_PSETTINGS');
$imageFile='icon-48-ProjectSettings.png';
$linkParams="<span>$text</span>&nbsp;";
$image=JHtml::_('image.administrator',$imageFile,$path,NULL,NULL,$text).$linkParams;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you're requesting, `JHtmlImage::administrator()`, does not exist in Joomla! 3.  Suggest you take a look at the `JHtml::image()` method as a replacement.